# Different endpoints become authorized seemingly randomly

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am writing an application, in which I am trying to configure different endpoints'  visibility.

I have written the following code:

```
@Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, UPVOTE_URL).authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, DOWNVOTE_URL).authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, LOG_OUT_URL).authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, DELETE_URL).authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ADD_URL).authenticated()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))      
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("No authorization"));
```

The behavior of my program is quite strange, because the program sometimes throws back 401 when I am trying to reach the "/login" or "/" endpoints (which afaik should redirect to the login page if the user has not signed in).

After that I restart it, maybe with some minor changes somewhere else, which are seemingly completely irrelevant, and my website works again.

Have any of you met these kinds of problems? What are the reasons of it? Have I done anything wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things that stand out here

1. You have a custom entry point, and the perception is that the entry point sends a 401, instead of redirect to /login
2. you don't have `formLogin()`, so the filter that handles login page is not in play
3. We don't know what your filters do and when

As for the configuration, let's start out first

```java
    http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, UPVOTE_URL).authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, DOWNVOTE_URL).authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, LOG_OUT_URL).authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, DELETE_URL).authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ADD_URL).authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), HeaderWriterFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()), JWTAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .logout()
        ;
```

So what did we change,

1. remove the authentication entry point and move the JWT filters to the front.
   If these filters trigger (and they should NOT trigger for non REST endpoint so you have to write that logic), then the system is either authenticated, of the filters themselves return 401 and not throw an exception. Maybe you can let us know if these filters actually do the right thing?
2. If the JWT filters do nothing, everything else come into play. So we have added in formLogin() with all the default configuration. If the authentication entry point is invoked because the request is not authenticated when it should be, a redirect to /login will happen